# Get the date of a minimum value from panda data series

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

Is there any (elegant) way to have the also the date of the minimum value found rather then just the stock value?

```
import datetime
from pandas_datareader import data

ticker  = 'V'
start = datetime.datetime(2010, 5, 15)
end = datetime.datetime(2010, 6, 15)
stock_values = data.DataReader(ticker,
                                  start=start,
                                  end=end,
                                  data_source='yahoo')

min_close_value = stock_values['Close'].min() # 17.522499084472656
# min_close_date =
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use argmin, which returns the index of the minimum:

```
index_of_min_close_value = stock_values['Close'].argmin()
```

Comment: Glad I could help! :) Happy Coding!